# WiFi stopped working after update (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

The Additional Drivers tab in Softwares & Updates says "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)".

Here's the output of `sudo lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
    Region 0: Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` :

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0655]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `modinfo wl | egrep 'file|verm'; uname -a` :

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
vermagic:       4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
Linux username-Inspiron-3543 4.4.0-116-generic #140~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 09:25:20 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` gives the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep gcc-5` :

```
ii  gcc-5                                                 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-5-base:amd64                                      5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc-5-dev:amd64                                    5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GCC support library (development files)
```

Output of `modinfo cfg80211`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
alias:          net-pf-16-proto-16-family-nl80211
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D2A8E57424453F0D1BE1DBE
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-116-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `modinfo wl | egrep 'file|verm'; uname -a`

Comment: Also: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Post results for `dpkg -l | grep gcc-5`

Comment: Also post results for `modinfo cfg80211`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Added.

Answer (score 0):

This is known to be caused by a gcc-5 version mismatch, we can try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-5 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot

Comment: Didn't work! I added the output of `dpkg -l | grep gcc-5` to the question. (I ran the command after trying out this solution).